# Vertical Parent and horizontal child?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've seen a few examples pertaining to the unification of container elements with selective scrolling capabilities, but none of them are really what I am looking for.

Basically I am working with SharePoint and trying to modify the seattle masterpage to handle content of unknown size across a responsive web design.  One example would be a large data table.

I decided the best option would be to have a fixed width of the content with a scroll effect across the x-axis, while the actual page section will handle vertical scrolling.  This way my header and footer are unaffected by the horizontal shifting and I don't get any odd whitespace popping up.

Example: [JsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/lazyhermit/4F9Pb/)

```
<div id='s4-workspace'>
<div id='contentBox'>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><div class='content'></div></td>
                <td><div class='content'></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class='content'></div></td>
                <td><div class='content'></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

But a problem occurs when interacting with a touch screen: I can't scroll up or down when interacting inside the content container unless I use two fingers to scroll.

**So just to reiterate**: on the seattle master page, I want the content(#contentBox) to take care of overflow-x, while the page(#s4-workspace) will handle overflow-y.  And I want the page to scroll while I am interacting with the content without resorting to using two fingers with working on a touchscreen device.

Anyone had this situation and can lead me in the right path?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using tables for layout? That's a bad practice.

Comment: @Diodeus : But I like the table.  What did it ever do wrong?

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, not layouts. They're a crutch for people who don't know how CSS works.

Comment: So then, your saying that overflow: auto won't work for you?

Comment: @Diodeus I know table elements are for tabular data.  What I provided was a basic example of how the web parts would be laid out in OOB page layouts so that it would be easier to distinguish what I am working with.

Comment: @nocturns2 overflow:auto works.  I am saying that interacting with a touchscreen device (i.e. iPhone, iPad) forces the user to use two-finger scrolling on the container with the web parts, but one-finger scrolling on the outer container.  I want the inner container to be fully functional with one finger.

I will update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem I have solved my own problem, which in turn has led to new cosmetic issues... :(

But no matter, those are different defects.  And for anyone who wants to know how this miracle can be achieved: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;`.  That's it.  Pop that style on the parent container and see the beauty that is not iOS native.

I just hope this works with an HTC tablet.